# Javascript/CSS -- apply css style on clicking unrelated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Javascript newbie question: I have a css image gallery utilising anchors in an unordered list:

```
<div id="gallery">
<ul id="gallery-interior">

<li id="one"><img src="../images/intro.jpg" usemap="#gallerymap"><map name="gallerymap">
<area shape="circ" coords="429,157,30" href="#two"></li>

<li id="two"><img src="../images/detail.jpg" usemap="#gallerymap_2"><map name="gallerymap_2">
<area shape="circ" coords="50,157,30" href="#one">
<area shape="circ" coords="429,157,30" href="#three"></li>

</ul>
</div>


#gallery {
width: 484px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 410px;
}

#gallery-interior {
overflow-y: hidden;
}

#gallery-interior li {
width: 484px;
height: 410px;
}
```

This gallery has thumbnails beneath that reference the anchors in the list to select images individually:

```
<div class='thumbs'>
<a href="#one"><img src="../images/intro_thumb.jpg"></a>
<a href="#two"><img src="../images/detail_thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

These thumbs are styled to change on selection:

```
.thumbs a:active img,
.thumbs a:focus img,
{
opacity:0.65;
-moz-opacity:0.65;
filter:alpha(opacity=65;
)
```

The thumbs respond to selection by changing opacity, but I'd like them to also change in response to clicking the links in the list, i.e., clicking <a href="#two"> at <li id="one"> would cause 'detail_thumb.jpg' to become opaque.

Is there a simple javascript solution to applying the '.thumbs a:active/focus img' class when clicking the list links ('<li id="one"><a href="#two"><img src="../images/intro.jpg">'</a>'</li>')? Css would be preferable, but combinators are apparently not applicable due to the lack of any dependencies between the gallery and the thumbnails (and an absolutely-positioned solution is undesirable).

If you feel that you can answer this question then please provide a coded example of your solution, as I have asked this question previously and only received continuous prose comments regarding a possible js direction and I am a stated newbie!

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: not sure but in your code the style will apply opacity when the element is only active and in focus. 
the element that was clicked will be still 'opaque' after the user holds the clicking the element or hovers out in the element, can you reprhase your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that the LI's are *always* going to match the ahrefs with imgs, all you have to do is attach a click event to the list items that "does stuff" to the matching img.  See

http://jsbin.com/bujayuku/1/

When you click #n in the list, do stuff to #n in the thumbs div.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Spanka. Yes, the LI's always match the img hrefs, but I can't get your code to work for me. Your jsbin functions as expected, but in looking for differences to diagnose the problem when placed in my code I note that you've dropped the hrefs from my list. I don't see that this should make any difference to the functionality, but it's the only real difference I can see. Is your "... $(this).index(); //1st li = 0, 2nd li = 1, etc. indx++; //done separately for demo only..." text germane here. The code should work, but I'm at something for a loss for why it doesn't...

Comment: QUick thing to check - your css posted originally uses opacity, -moz-opacity & filter:alpha(opacity).  You might want to update .dimmed to be a little more...overbearing :)

.thumbs a .dimmed, .thumbs .dimmed, .dimmed  { 
opacity: 0.5 !important;
-moz-opacity: 0.5 !important;
filter:alpha(opacity=65) !important;
}

Additionally, you might have to adapt the jq to modify/REMOVE the underlying CSS properties provided by the script on hover/click etc.

If you can give me a sample, post a link, PM me something, I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Code is still local Spanka and not live yet, so link not poss. PM sounds good; I can't see any contact details for you, but I can be contacted at mywifenowdave@gmail.com. Yes, I already bumped the opacity up to make sure I wasn't missing it, but no-go. cheers, D

Comment: Solved by Spanka via PM-tennis with js code that is as ingenious as it is elegant. Will update code in original question with solution for benefit of other users. Good on ya Mate!